# How to make YouTube embeds 100% width with React

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube

I used the `fitvids()` library in the past but it does not work well with React. Ho can I make my videos 100% of the width in React?

Comment: This project has no stars, but sounds like what you are looking for https://github.com/LeisureLink-FE/react-flexifit. otherwise, you can take the ideas from this article and apply them to your React code https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: You could track the width of the page manually via window events and pass that to the youtube component as a prop.

Comment: Read this article. I think it can help you not use React in this case. https://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code with 'component-dom' because I wanted something lighter weight then jQuery, but you can easily adjust the DOM traversal for use with jQuery. Also, I'm forcing everything to widescreen. FYI, I cant' remember where I got the window resizing code from, hate not to give credit.

```
updateVideoDimensions() {
    var allVideos = dom("#post-content").find("iframe[src*='player.vimeo.com']," + 
        "iframe[src*='youtube.com']," + 
        "iframe[src*='youtube-nocookie.com']," + 
        "iframe[src*='kickstarter.com'][src*='video.html']," + 
        "object," + 
        "embed");

    allVideos.each(function() {
        let width = (this).parent()[0].offsetWidth;

        (this)
        .attr('height', (width * 720) / 1280)
        .attr('width', width);
    });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateVideoDimensions();
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateVideoDimensions);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateVideoDimensions);
}
```